# oracle how to calculate duration in weeks and days or days and months?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, duration

I've been trying to get the duration between two dates in my question's particular format. It would be easy for duration in days as we can subtract or if it's in months, we can use the `months_between` function..

i would need it to convert in weeks and days.. the other one would be months and days.. is there a function that can do this in oracle? i've been searching online if anyone is doing something similar like i need to achieve to, but cant seem to find a close one.

Could anyone help me on this?

im using oracle 11g.

examples : range between 2014/12/16 and 2014/12/01 is **2weeks 1day**

Thanks.

Comment: Please show an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: OldProgrammer, i've edited the question and added the example..my user wants to view it in that format instead of just showing (days).

Answer (score 0):

Converting a raw number of days into a number of weeks and days is pretty simple.  Just divide the total by 7 to get the weeks and then calculate the remaining days

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    total_days integer;
  3    total_weeks integer;
  4    remaining_days integer;
  5  begin
  6    total_days := date '2014-12-16' - date '2014-12-01';
  7    total_weeks := total_days/ 7;
  8    remaining_days := total_days - total_weeks * 7;
  9    dbms_output.put_line( total_weeks || ' weeks, ' || remaining_days || ' days.' );
 10* end;
SQL> /
2 weeks, 1 days.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Months and days is a bit more complicated because that's not very well defined-- you'll have to define a number of rules.  For example, `months_between` returns 1 for the number of months between November 30 and December 30.  It also returns 1 for the number of months between November 30 and December 31.  Is that the result that you would want?  Or do you always want your displayed difference to increase if the number of days between the two dates increases?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one it may help you, you can rearrange the output as per your need, as its display is not much clear to me with reference to your question,generally we consider month as of 30 days so i used divide by 30.

```
create or replace function timediff(fdate date,tdate date) 
return varchar2
as
tot_duration varchar2(25);
begin
    select floor(days/30)||' Month '||floor(mod(days,30)/7)||' Week '
    ||mod(mod(days,30),7)||' Day ' into tot_duration
    from
      (
      select (tdate-fdate) days from dual
      );
return tot_duration;
end;/
```

Call the above function:-

```
select timediff('10.nov.2014','30.dec.2014') duration from dual;
```

Output result:-

```
Duration 
1 Month 2 Week 6 Day
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL`, you could achieve this using `TRUNC` and `ROUND` with the logic that difference in days needs to be divided by 7 to get the number of weeks.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT DATE '2014-12-16' start_dt, DATE '2014-12-01' end_dt FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT TRUNC((start_dt -end_dt)/7)
  5    ||' weeks '
  6    || ROUND(((start_dt -end_dt)/7 - TRUNC((start_dt -end_dt)/7))*7)
  7    || ' days' week_days
  8  FROM DATA
  9  /

WEEK_DAYS
--------------
2 weeks 1 days

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This query give you months/weeks/days of a range of dates:

```
SELECT trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN (end_date, start_date)) months, 
floor((end_date - add_months( start_date, trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN (end_date, start_date)) ))/7) weeks,
mod(end_date - add_months( start_date, trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN (end_date, start_date)) ),7) days 
      FROM (SELECT TO_DATE ('2014/12/16', 'yyyy/mm/dd') end_date,
                   TO_DATE ('2014/12/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') start_date
              FROM DUAL);
```

You can also format it as you want. For example:

```
SELECT trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN (end_date, start_date)) || 'months ' || 
floor((end_date - add_months( start_date, trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN (end_date, start_date)) ))/7) ||'weeks '||
mod(end_date - add_months( start_date, trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN (end_date, start_date)) ),7) ||'days' date_values
      FROM (SELECT TO_DATE ('2014/12/16', 'yyyy/mm/dd') end_date ,
                   TO_DATE ('2014/12/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') start_date
              FROM DUAL);
```

Returns:

```
DATE_VALUES         
--------------------
0months 2weeks 1days.
```

I hope this helps you. Sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION time_spell(p_days VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_y NUMBER;
v_yd NUMBER;
v_m NUMBER;
v_md NUMBER;
v_d NUMBER;
v_w NUMBER;
v_wd NUMBER;
v_days NUMBER;
v_yi NUMBER;
v_mi NUMBER;
v_wi  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT p_days/365 INTO v_y FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_y) INTO v_yi FROM dual;
select substr(v_y,(select instr(v_y,'.') from dual)) INTO v_yd from dual;
SELECT v_yd * 12 INTO v_m FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_m) INTO v_mi FROM dual;
select substr(v_m,(select instr(v_m,'.') from dual)) INTO v_md from dual;
SELECT v_md * 30 INTO v_d FROM dual;
SELECT v_d / 7 INTO v_w FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_w) INTO v_wi FROM dual;
select substr(v_w,(select instr(v_w,'.') from dual)) INTO v_wd from dual;
SELECT trunc(v_wd * 7) INTO v_days FROM dual;
RETURN v_yi||' Year(s) '||v_mi||' Month(s) '||v_wi||' Week(s) '||v_days||' Day(s) ';
END;
```

[select time_spell(sysdate- to_date('27-Jul-2014','DD-Mon-YYYY')) from dual;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U6TX.jpg)